# Any way to generate multiple different pdfs from single Sphinx configuration

Tags: python, pdf, python-sphinx

I have a nice Sphinx documentation concerning a projects, and I would like to extend it to generate documents such as specs, and other. I would like to have `spec-for-foo.rst` that generates `spec-for-foo.pdf`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to edit `latex_documents` entry in your sphinx `conf.py` file, this entry contains descriptors for all the files produced by `latex` .

This config entry contains a list of touples, that contains: (source file, target tex file, document title, author, and document class:

```
latex_documents = [
   ('index', 'Kaskady.tex', u'Kaskady  Documentation',
    u'Author', 'manual'),
   ('profile', 'profiles.tex', u'Wyznaczanie profili', 
    u'Author', 'howto'),
]
```

Comment: There are a few additional options now, see [docs](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-latex_documents): `(startdocname, targetname, title, author, theme, toctree_only)`