# Can I build multiple PDFs from the same source in readthedocs?

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs, latexmk

I have a lot of documentation in a readthedocs site, and I'd like to be able to serve it as two separate PDF files.  I've separated the contents for each into two top-level *.rst files (`formal.rst` and `informal.rst`), specified them both in the conf.py (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879276/any-way-to-generate-multiple-different-pdfs-from-single-sphinx-configuration)), but I'm struggling with an error during the build:

```
Latexmk: Need to specify at most one filename if jobname specified, 
    but 2 were found (after defaults and wildcarding).
```

I'm not sure whether it's possible for readthedocs to build more than one PDF?  If not, does that mean I should have an entirely separate branch ...? or ...?

conf.py:

```
latex_documents = [
    ('formal', 'formal.tex', u'My stuff', u'My contributors', 'manual'),
    ('informal', 'informal.tex', u'My stuff', u'My contributors', 'manual'),
]
```

Comment: entirely separate branch should work

Comment: It does work (sorry, I should have mentioned that in the text) but I don't want to have to maintain two separate branches for the same source code, if it's possible to avoid it.  If not, I guess I'll just have to suck it up ... but it's far from ideal!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it's not possible to output more than one PDF file per build. This is a limitation. There is an issue opened at https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/2045 in case you want to subscribe to follow up with the news.